# Сложный sql запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Таблица 1
`roller`

`id | type_roller | name_file | filepath | time_start | time_stop | period | user_id | tc_servers | timeRolik`

Таблица 2
`roller_priority`

`id | user_id | tc_id | roller_id | priority`

текущая выборка из Таблицы 1

```
SELECT *
FROM roller
WHERE
  time_stop >= '2013.02.05'
  AND time_start <= '2013.02.05'
  AND user_id = 1
  AND (tc_servers LIKE '44;%' OR tc_servers LIKE '%;44;%' OR tc_servers LIKE '%;44' OR tc_servers = '44')

  AND (period = 6 OR period = 3)
//*эта строчка подставляется в php*// //*либо AND (period = 6)*//
```

к этой выборке нужно прикрутить сортировку по второй таблице

из Таблицы 2 делать выборку строк по

`roller | roller_priority
user_id == user_id
id == roller_id`

на основе этого приклеить к Таблице 1 столбец **priority** и отсортировать по нему Таблицу 1.

Comment: ...   AND tc_servers LIKE '%44%' ...

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, уточнил свой ответ по вашему комментарию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите сделать запрос на выборку из двух таблиц?

Олдскул:

```
SELECT r.*, rp.priority
  FROM roller AS r,
       roller_priority AS rp
 WHERE r.time_stop  >= '2013.02.05'
   AND r.time_start <= '2013.02.05'
   AND r.user_id = 1
   AND r.tc_servers LIKE '%44%'
   AND (   r.period = 6 
        OR r.period = 3)
   AND r.user_id = rp.user_id
   AND r.id = rp.roller_id
 ORDER BY rp.priority
```

Ньюскул:

```
SELECT r.*, rp.priority
  FROM roller AS r
  JOIN roller_priority AS rp
    ON r.user_id = rp.user_id
   AND r.id = rp.roller_id
 WHERE r.time_stop  >= '2013.02.05'
   AND r.time_start <= '2013.02.05'
   AND r.user_id = 1
   AND r.tc_servers LIKE '%44%'
   AND (   r.period = 6 
        OR r.period = 3)
 ORDER BY rp.priority
```

UPD. Уточнил запрос по комментарию [[@Vfvtnjd](/users/4996/vfvtnjd)](/users/4996/vfvtnjd)

```
   AND r.tc_servers LIKE '%44%'
```